# Extracting contours bounding boxes for ROI's from image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, tesseract, contour

I am trying to extract bounding boxes from this [form](http://eclipsecorp.us/__--eclipsecorp--__/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/DocOrigin_Government_W2_2014_Red-ScanL.jpg) image. The Bounding Boxes in my case are all the boxes in the image. My approach was to Find contours, obtain the bounding box, extract the ROI and perform OCR using pytesseract on those ROI's. I am not able to find the right contours. Is my approach the right way or should I try a different solution. Thanks in advance.

My code so far looks as follows

```
import cv2
import pytesseract


image = cv2.imread('DocOrigin_Government_W2_2014_Red-ScanL.jpg')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2) #adaptive
canny = cv2.Canny(thresh, 100, 200)


# Find contours, obtain bounding box, extract and save ROI
ROI_number = 0
cnts = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    # x,y,w,h = 37, 625, 309, 28  
    ROI = thresh[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(ROI, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
    print(data)
    # write contour images to disk
    # cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
    # cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
    # ROI_number += 1
```

Comment: External contours will not work. It will only find the outer rectangle. Your need to use RETR_TREE.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for the suggestion. I made that change in the code. Still I'm not sure as to how to get the bounding boxes of the cells though.

Comment: I would just threshold on red using cv2.inRange(). Then get the contours from that. Then the bounding boxes of those contours should find each cell.

Comment: Do the dotted-lines count towards the individual boxes?

Comment: Yes dotted lines also count toward boxes.